# Image not showing up in Jekyll post but shows up locally

Tags: html, css, ruby, github, jekyll

Here is my website

https://garyzhubc.github.io/life-style/2018/06/10/steam-fish.html

I have a folder called assets and I'm referencing the images from the post in this way

```
![steam-fish-1]({{ "/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" | absolute_url }})
```

by following what I've seen from the tutorial at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/

But the images showing up as little question marks. How should I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add `https://` at the starting of the image url like

`garyzhubc.github.io/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg`

to

`https://garyzhubc.github.io/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg`

because `garyzhubc.github.io/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg` url is redirecting to the `https://garyzhubc.github.io/life-style/2018/06/10/garyzhubc.github.io/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg` which is not the url of image

Answer (score 1):

Your `url` is not correctly set in *_config.yml*.

It must be : `url: https://garyzhubc.github.io`

You can then call your images with `![steam-fish-1]({{ "/assets/steam-fish-1.jpeg" | absolute_url }})`.

Comment: Basically no double quote? Can you please explain? I though with or without double quote are the same.

Comment: It's effectively the same.